# How to Elevate Role in ASP.net From anonymous to windows auth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have a few websites which allow both anonymous and window auth users at the same time. Basically if you hit the site with IE or Webkit based browsers on a windows system, the server instantly recognizes your active directory user and group.

In the past I've provided a link to a windows auth only page which allows the current user to login, or bounce back to where they started.

I find the management of this kind of frustrating as I need to make certain that IIS has the correct security settings for that single page after every deployment.

Is there a better way for me to allow a user to elevate from anon to authenticated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out a fairly nice way to do this...however it's not as elegant as I had hoped since it doesn't work across applications.

Basically, if you create a single page within your Anon + Integrated Auth IIS6 website or virtual directory, let's call it auth.aspx, then you can use this page to prompt authentication.

Go into IIS settings and specify that auth.aspx is Integrated Auth ONLY (no anon). Then create a hidden iframe somewhere on your page. I then created a simple JavaScript action to update the src attribute of the iframe to the auth.aspx page. This forces the browser to try and authenticate using NTLM. Once you enter valid credentials you've successfully elevated your current user beyond the generic anonymous user.

One final touch was to then include a Response.Redirect into the auth.aspx which reloads the current page. Assuming your ASP.net session tokens are set correctly, the page will reload and the user will be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to do that elevation automatically. The server can't know that the current user is a Windows user and elevate them, or automatically redirect them to the Windows auth only page. On the other hand, if every user will get through the Windows auth only page, all of them which are not inside the domain will see the challenge/response dialog box (user + password).

As for the management part of making sure that this special page has the correct security settings, you can (and should) automate the check somehow. For example, by querying the [IIS metabase](http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-advanced/iis-metabase-and-programmatic-administration-in-c.aspx) for that setting when the application starts (in Global.asax) and if the setting is not there, log it as an email message or so.

Personally I prefer a different attitude - a special "integration/deployment" page which contains a series of tests against my application so I can make sure everything's set up correctly on the server, i.e. NTFS write permissions to certain folders, availability of the SMTP server set in web.config to send emails through, etc.

**Note:** You're using Windows authentication along with anonymous access. Just keep in mind that if you consider implementing Forms Authentication in the future, a misarchitecture (I don't know if by design or due to a flaw) of IIS 7 does not allow you to set the app to be Forms Authentication and set one specific page to be Windows Authentication. The override just doesn't work and it's very frustrating.

Good luck!

Comment: Great comment on IIS7 as I'll be moving to that shortly. I've got a couple of ideas I'm going to bang around, but your comment certainly helps.